# IndexError in array PYTHON

Tags: c#, python, arrays, function, python-3.x

I am tring to write this C# function in Python, unfortunatly I have this **ERROR**: `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` in `Population.BinaryX.insert([i][j], dec)` line. Can anyone tell me how can I fix this problem?! What`s wrong I did?

**C# CODE:**

```
public class Population
    {
        public float[] CodedX = new float[20];
        public float[,] BinaryX = new float[10, 8];
    }

private void BinaryTranslating()
        {
            int dec;
            int j = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                while (Population.CodedX[i] > 1 & j < 8)
                {
                    dec = (int)Population.CodedX[i] % 2;
                    Population.BinaryX[i, j] = dec;
                    Population.CodedX[i] /= 2;
                    j++;
                }
                j = 0;
            }
        }

 private void DecimalTranslating()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Population.CodedX[i] = Population.BinaryX[i, 7] * 128 + Population.BinaryX[i, 6] * 64 + 
                                       Population.BinaryX[i, 5] * 32 + Population.BinaryX[i, 4] * 16 + 
                                       Population.BinaryX[i, 3] * 8 + Population.BinaryX[i, 2] * 4 + 
                                       Population.BinaryX[i, 1] * 2 + Population.BinaryX[i, 0];

            }
        }
```

**Python CODE:**

```
class Population:
CodedX = []
BinaryX = [[], []]

class Application:
@staticmethod
    def binary_translating():
        j = 0
        for i in range(10):
            while Population.CodedX[i] > 1 & j < 8:
                dec = int(Population.CodedX[i]) % 2
                Population.BinaryX.insert([i][j], dec)
                Population.CodedX[i] /= 2
                j += 1
            j = 0

@staticmethod
    def decimal_translating():
        for i in range(10):
            new_item = Population.BinaryX[i][7] * 128 + Population.BinaryX[i][6] * 64 + Population.BinaryX[i][5] * 32 +\
                       Population.BinaryX[i][4] * 16 + Population.BinaryX[i][3] * 8 + Population.BinaryX[i][2] * 4 +\
                       Population.BinaryX[i][1] * 2 + Population.BinaryX[i][0]
            Population.CodedX.insert(i, new_item)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a bitwise AND for booleans, use the proper "and" operator in Python.

Comment: Can you show us how you define `Population.BinaryX`?

Comment: Can you post a sample for CodedX? and what is BinaryX?

Comment: `[i][j]` doesn't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: is `BinaryX` a multidimensional list/array?

Comment: Hello to everyone! @danidee Yes, BinaryX is multidimensional list.

Comment: @zoubida Do you have any ideas how to fix this problem?! I am really comfused.

Comment: @WreckeR I update my post. Can you check it again?! I updated it with new funcation which connected with last one, also the place where I defined `Population.BinaryX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please make sure that `Population.BinaryX` is a valid entity and has at least 10 element in it because you are running the loop 10 times. Same goes for `CodedX`.

If either of them do not have at least 10 elements, you will get

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Try..

```
class Population:
    CodedX = [0 for i in range(10)]
    BinaryX = [[0 for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
```

This is preallocating as mentioned by tdelaney.

If you look at each functions in the Application class, they try to use either BinaryX or CodedX arrays but if these arrays do not have any elements in them, then how will python index into them?

What I mean is before calling the `decimal_translating()` function, the `Population.BinrayX` must have elements in it. It cannot be empty array.

Similarly, before calling the `binary_translating()` function, `Population.CodedX` must have elements in it.

**[edit #1]**
After your comments and trying to understand your code.Here is what I have:-

```
class Population(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.CodedX = [0 for i in range(10)]  # as per your C# code
        self.BinaryX = []
        # debug code to fill CodedX array - remove it
        for i in range(10):
            self.CodedX[i] = int(761)

    def binary_translating(self):
        for i in range(10):
            j = 0
            self.BinaryX.append([0 for k in range(10)])
            while (self.CodedX[i] > 0) and (j < 10):
                dec = int(self.CodedX[i] % 2)
                self.BinaryX[i][j] = dec  # this will append at j
                self.CodedX[i] = int(self.CodedX[i] / 2)
                j += 1
        # debug code to print - remove it
        print(self.BinaryX)
        # debug code to clear CodedX - remove it
        for i in range(10):
            self.CodedX[i] = int(0)

    def decimal_translating(self):
        for i in range(10):
            value = self.BinaryX[i][7] * 128 + self.BinaryX[i][6] * 64 + self.BinaryX[i][5] * 32 + \
                             self.BinaryX[i][4] * 16 + self.BinaryX[i][3] * 8 + self.BinaryX[i][2] * 4 + \
                             self.BinaryX[i][1] * 2 + self.BinaryX[i][0]
            self.CodedX[i] = value
        print(self.CodedX)


pop = Population()

pop.binary_translating()
pop.decimal_translating()
```

I have added some debug code to have some starting values in `CodedX` and print statements for you to see the output.

generates the output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]

[249, 249, 249, 249, 249, 249, 249, 249, 249, 249]
```

**[edit #2]**[image: this is what i meant by the conversion precision]

Comment: Hello @Mrunmoy I checked  program right now and I have elements in Population.CodedX. Also I noticed interesting think when I wrote `BinaryX = [[0 for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]` it work but when I wrote as `BinaryX = [[0 for i in range(8)] for j in range(10)]` it didnt work. So I am little bit comfused about that. Do you have any ideas?!

Comment: By the way, `Population.BinrayX` I use first time in `binary_translating()` function so its anyway empty at start. What to do in that cause?

Comment: As I understand I need to add element to `Population.BinrayX` but how to use .append to multidimensional array in that cause?!

Comment: Do you mean that `Population.BinaryX` filled be zero to begin with? or it should be empty ?

Comment: It was empty then in that `binary_translating()` function I add elements to `Population.BinrayX`. No zero elements just empty at start. That`s how I understand.

Comment: You can make the functions static, if you want it that way.

Comment: The output of `CodedX` is different that what I had filled because you have used 8 bit conversion for the `decimal_translating()` function but 10-bits for the `binary_translating()` function. If you make that 8-bit then the results will match. i.e. 761 in 8-bits will be 249.

Comment: change values in these two lines from 10 to 8 . `self.BinaryX.append([0 for k in range(10)])
            while (self.CodedX[i] > 0) and (j < 10)`

Comment: Hello again! You mean to change both 10 values to 8? There`s no error but programm still work strange. I am confused with multidimensional list in Python. How too add and change element in  multidimensional list. Anyway BIG THANKS!

Comment: I asked to change the 10 to 8 because that will change the precision of conversion. By changing the 10 to 8 you will convert to 8 bit binary instead of 10-bit binary, so the values which you can convert will be limited to 8-bit values.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the `[i][j]` expression in `Population.BinaryX.insert([i][j], dec)`. That expression creates a 1 item list containing the value of `i` and then tries to take the `j`th item from that list.

```
>>> i=1
>>> j=2
>>> [i][j]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Python lists are one dimensional and if you want a multidimensional list, you need to create a list of lists or use some other structure such as a `numpy` or `pandas` array.

One option is to preallocate the array with a known value so that you can simply index it later

```
@staticmethod
def binary_translating():
    Population.BinaryX = [[None] * 8 for _ in range(10)]
    j = 0
    for i in range(10):
        while Population.CodedX[i] > 1 & j < 8:
            dec = int(Population.CodedX[i]) % 2
            Population.BinaryX[i][j] = dec
            Population.CodedX[i] /= 2
            j += 1
        j = 0
```

Another option is to insert into the sublist:

```
@staticmethod
def binary_translating():
    Population.BinaryX = []
    j = 0
    for i in range(10):
        Population.BinaryX.insert([])
        while Population.CodedX[i] > 1 & j < 8:
            dec = int(Population.CodedX[i]) % 2
            Population.BinaryX[i].insert(j, dec)
            Population.CodedX[i] /= 2
            j += 1
        j = 0
```

Comment: I am tring to use your first version and I have question can we write like this `Population.BinaryX[i][j] = dec` It gives `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` What do you this about that?

Comment: Can you check my post again pls. I updated it with new funcation which connected with last one, alos the place where I defined `Population.BinaryX`.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek - I was away from my computer for awhile... glad to see the other answer worked it through for you!